# Remove all Ul's  that does not contain a custom attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, custom-attributes

I want to remove only those ul with li that doesn't have a custom attribute on it. I was trying this

```
$myParent.children('li ul:not("ul[isClicked=True]")').remove();
```

but can't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>If I understand you correctly, you want to remove the `ul`s that contain `li`s with the attribute `isClicked` = `"True"`:</s>

```
$myParent.find("li[isClicked=True]").parent("ul").remove();
```

Note that the attribute must contain the word `"True"`; it's a string, not a boolean.

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/otowes)

From your comment below:

> I am looking for vice-versa actually. Remove all ul's that don't have the custom attribute.

That's the opposite of the opening sentence of your question (*"I want to remove only those ul with li that have a custom attribute on it"*). :-) Here's how you'd do that assuming the `ul` elements are direct children of `$myParent` (your example code suggests this); if that's not true, just change the `.children` on the first line to `.find`:

```
$myParent.children("ul").each(function() {
  var $ul = $(this);
  if (!$ul.find("li[isClicked=True]")[0]) {
    // Doesn't have one, remove it
    $ul.remove();
  }
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/otowes/2)

---

FWIW, that attribute name won't [validate](http://validator.w3.org). You might consider switching to the [`data-*` attribute form](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes).

Comment: I am looking for vice-versa actually. Remove all ul's that don't have the custom attribute.

Comment: @ankur: That's the opposite of what the opening sentence of your question says.